# ¿Como puedo ordenar un vector de una estructura de datos? C++

Tags: c++

Mi programa captura entre 5 y 10 viajeros en un vector llamado viajero[10] luego de eso se debe llenar el vector con el nombre la cantidad de horas de minutos y segundos, que tardo el viajero en llegar a su destino.

Después tiene que ordenarlos de manera que el primer lugar sea para el viajero que gastó menos tiempo y el ultimo para el  que gasto mas tiempo.

Mi problema es ¿Cómo puedo ordenar el vector  viajeros[i].nombre sin que se intercambie las horas de los viajeros?.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
char a=160, e=130, ii=161, o=162, u=163, n=164;

struct viajeros{
    char nombre[30];
    int horas;
    int minutos;
    int segundos;
    int totaldetodo;
}viajero[10], totaltiempo[10];;

int tam = 0;
void ordenarBurbuja();
void menu();
void crear();
void llenar();
void mostrar();
float totalsegundos[10];
float ordenviajeros[10];
int main(){
    system("color 0a");
    menu(); 
}

void menu(){

    char opcion;

    cout<<"\n  Men"<<u<<endl;
    cout<<"a) Crear"<<endl;
    cout<<"b) Llenar"<<endl;
    cout<<"c) Mostrar"<<endl;
    cout<<"d) Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"Digite su Opci"<<o<<"n: ";
    cin>>opcion;

    switch(opcion){
        case 'a': crear(); menu(); break;
        case 'b': llenar(); menu(); break;
        case 'c': mostrar(); menu(); break;
        case 'd': cout<<"\n----- Hasta luego -----\n"; break;
        default : cout<<"\n***** Opci"<<o<<"n NO v"<<a<<"lida *****\n"; menu(); break;
    }
}

void crear(){

    cout<<"\nDigite la cantidad de viajeros ";
    cin>>tam;
    if(tam>=5 && tam<=10)
    {
        tam=tam;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Solo puede ingresar entre 5 y 10 viajeros ";
        crear();

    }           
}

void llenar(){

    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
        cout<<"\nDigite el nombre del viajero "<<i+1<<" ";
        cin.getline(viajero[i].nombre,30);  
        cin.getline(viajero[i].nombre,30);  
        regresarhoras:      
        cout<<"\nDigite las horas que se demor"<<o<<" el viajero "<<viajero[i].nombre<<" en llegar  ";  

        cin>>viajero[i].horas;
        totaltiempo[i].horas =  viajero[i].horas * 3600;
        if (viajero[i].horas<0){
            cout<<"\nLas horas no pueden ser negativas";
            goto regresarhoras;
        }else
        {       
        regresarminutos:    
        cout<<"\nDigite los minutos que se demor"<<o<<" el viajero "<<viajero[i].nombre<<" en llegar  "; 
        cin>>viajero[i].minutos;
        totaltiempo[i].minutos = viajero[i].minutos * 60;
            if (viajero[i].minutos<0){
                cout<<"\nLos minutis no pueden ser negativos";
            goto regresarminutos;
            }
            else{
                regresarsegundos:

        cout<<"\nDigite los segundos que se demor"<<o<<" el viajero "<<viajero[i].nombre<<" en llegar  ";
        cin>>viajero[i].segundos;
        totaltiempo[i].segundos =   viajero[i].segundos;
        if (viajero[i].segundos<0){
            cout<<"\nLos segundos no pueden ser negativos";
            goto regresarsegundos;
            }


        }




    }
    viajero[i].totaldetodo = totaltiempo[i].segundos + totaltiempo[i].minutos + totaltiempo[i].horas ;
    totalsegundos[i]=viajero[i].totaldetodo;
    ordenviajeros[i]=totalsegundos[i];



  }

}

void mostrar(){
    ordenarBurbuja();

    cout<<"\nViajeros por orden de ingreso";
    cout<<"\n--------------";
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
        cout<<"\nEl viajero "<<viajero[i].nombre<<" se demor"<<o<<" "<<viajero[i].horas<<" horas con "<<viajero[i].minutos<<" minutos y "<<viajero[i].segundos<<" segundos"<<endl;                  
    }
cout<<endl;




cout<<"\nViajeros por orden de tiempo";
    cout<<"\n--------------";
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
        cout<<"\nEl viajero "<<viajero[i].nombre <<"se demor"<<o<<" "<<totalsegundos[i]<<" horas con "<< totalsegundos[i]/60 <<" minutos y "<<totalsegundos[i]<<" segundos"<<endl;                  
    }










    /*
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
        cout<<"\n"<<(i+1)<<") La pel"<<ii<<"cula "<<peliculas[i].titulo
            <<" publicada en el a"<<n<<"o "<<peliculas[i].anio_publicacion
            <<"\ntiene una duraci"<<o<<"n de "<<peliculas[i].duracion<<" horas "
            <<"y es de g"<<e<<"nero "<<peliculas[i].genero<<endl;   
    }
    */
}
void ordenarBurbuja(){
    int aux;
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tam-1;j++){
            if(totalsegundos[j]<totalsegundos[j+1]){
                aux=totalsegundos[j];
                totalsegundos[j]=totalsegundos[j+1];
                totalsegundos[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hola no entiendo bien por que se te intercambiarían las horas ? si vos comparas totaldetodo suponiendo que ese sea el elemento para comparar y ordenar . ? si es asi podes usar un puntero para no perder la referencia y haces el intercambio del indice del arreglo . osea usarias el mismo arreglo para capturar y ordenar no te aria gfalta otro arreglo . o tal vez entendí mal la pregunta ?

Answer (score 1):

Para ordenar una colección de datos, usa [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) de `<algorithm>`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(viajero), std::end(viajero));
```

Esa línea, tal y como está te fallará, porque el compilador no sabe cómo comparar dos objetos de tipo `viajeros`.

Tienes dos opciones para solucionar el problema:

- Pasa una lambda que sirva de comparador:

  ```
  std::sort(std::begin(viajero), std::end(viajero),
      [](const auto &a, const auto &b)
      {
          return a.totaldetodo < b.totaldetodo;
      });
  ```
- Crea un operador de comparación visible desde la llamada a `std::sort`:

  ```
  bool operator<(const viajeros &a, const viajeros &b)
  {
      return a.totaldetodo < b.totaldetodo;
  }

  int main()
  {
      viajeros viajero[10] { /* datos */ };

      std::sort(std::begin(viajero), std::end(viajero));

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFNb4MwDIbP5FdYnbQWiVb9uBXUYw877d71EILHMtEYBdNLxW9nCV@DS5L3cfzaTlRZbnOl2vZNG1XUGUKiqWKL8nER/8wRbfI5kUVOVvPP4ppmtJLJXoRwGbVieGr5i5bgJYKKs/O5NwJDj9RiLAJtGJhYFhkyZRSLJhbCw4fUZhMKlzdaDHt1O@zvInCB4LX6xBJXERz2TdRrqcjp4yix1F5OYV1Kp0@jpCF7iqMdwEg@qMK5w1Ub73A8jiWuWPgSh@NputGDRgR@lmFssrzpTinmbrBxljCCjqLJ5ux23ygyFYOsmeBdRjCXaegLgUWurQG5m70fJJAudAxN6Lv4JgsLzyecpxf1fl0bimqGJIHnrv8gf17B9uKWji4qJbD@MmtvPnSyd7/Xtn8)</kbd>.

---

Por cierto, no tiene sentido que el objeto que almacena datos de un viajero tenga el nombre en plural (`viajeros`) mientras que la colección de viajeros tenga el nombre en singular (`viajero[10]`).

Comment: Vale intentaré implementar tu solucion pero es posible comunicarme por discord con tigo ?

Comment: Si tienes dudas sobre el código, te animo a editar la pregunta o hacer una pregunta nueva, de esta manera, las respuestas que recibas serán útiles  para otros usuarios en el futuro.